# binding_of_caller gem not being invoked in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, railsapps, better-errors-gem

I really like the better_errors gem in development and on my os x machine get the REPL to appear. Now I'm learning the vagaries of Windows XP and find that while better_errors works, the REPL does not appear, helpfully suggesting I install the binding_of_caller gem. Starting from a RailsApp starter my gemfile shows the below:

```
 group :development do
   gem 'better_errors'
   gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
   gem 'quiet_assets'
   gem 'rails_layout'
 end
```

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0-p353 using pik 0.3.0 pre. I have run gem install binding_of_caller and I saw no errors installing. Here's my output of bundle show _binding_of_caller_

```
 Could not find gem 'binding_of_caller' Did you mean binding_of_caller?
```

I've commented out the call to the platforms in the GemfileOK, but the REPL is still not loading.

my Windows fu is not very bright, but I haven't found anything on Google that would suggest a solution. Reading up on the github page suggests I'm not doing anything wrong. What should I try next? thanx, sam

I've just moved my app to a new Win7 machine. Unfortunately, binding_of_caller is still not being raised, though it works fine on my OS X machine. So there's something on Windows I'm not doing right.

Comment: Please tell me that someone is forcing you to use winxp and it's not your own decision. :)

Comment: Yes, forcing, but a Win7 is coming soon. However, I don't expect that to be a panacea. Pls tell me I'm wrong about that. :-)

Comment: Well, some things are known to be broken on windows. Some are explicitly not supported. So I decided not to care about it. :) Hope you'll find your solution.